# How to add dialog box on webpage with Chrome Extension?

Tags: dialog, google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know how to add a dialog box similar to the one used by Google's Voice extension (it's the one in the blue activated by clicking on the phone number)?

[image]

Thanks, 
Joe Chin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome doesn't come with any GUI API. Everything you see is made in plain javascript and css. You would need to either find some js library that helps with creating dialogs, or style them yourself (that's what that Google Voice extension looks like is doing).

Comment: Yep. Use Javascript to create DOM elements that you can position with `position: absolute`.

Comment: Right, I totally understand this. The problem I have is understanding how to signal to the extension that a specific element has been clicked and that an action needs to be started.

Comment: @JoeChin You would need to inject a content script to that site and then you can listen to dom events, just like if you were doing it in regular js on your site.

Comment: @serg Hi Serg, I have a content script that I was injecting into the site. However, when I click on the element it says the clickHandler() function I have defined in my content script is not defined on the site. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.... sigh.

Comment: @JoeChin Maybe you would like to create a new question dedicated to that problem then, as it seems unrelated to the current question.